# Why can't I call protocol method from class method?

Tags: swift

The code below compiles just fine if I make the tester() method an instance method. How can I make it work while keeping it a class method?

```
protocol Numbers {
}

extension Numbers {
    func amountFromText(text: String) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}

class CommonDB: Numbers {
    class func tester() {
        let text = ""
        let amount = amountFromText(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't call instance methods in a static way.

Comment: @nhgrif Thus the question. Why down vote a legitimate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your function defined in your protocol means that it will be an instance function, that is, you need an instance of the class or structure in order to call that function.  When you are in a class function, you don't have an instance of that class.

If you want to call `amountFromText()` from a class function, then declare it to be `static`.  That way, it won't need an instance of the class or structure to be called:

```
extension Numbers {
    static func amountFromText(text: String) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm that works, but causes problems for cases where I do have a class instance. Giving you the points for the answer tho.  Instead, I made sure I have a static instance variable of the class and refer to the method through that variable.